# How does two threads not able to execute method at the same time. Internally what happens in the code.

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method which is synchronized defined in some class.

We know that if we create a method as synchronized, then only one thread is able to execute the task at a time.

What is happening inside this method ?

How does other thread not able to execute the same task to run same method.

As per my knowledge, join is applied on that particular thread. But how does the second thread in the pipeline knows about the task has been done by first thread.

Tell me if i am right.

Comment: @EvanKnowles - please elaborate - *Not a join, a lock*. The OP is getting confused between this statement and my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We know that if we create a method as synchronized, then only one thread is able to execute the task at a time.

Not True!  Two or more threads *can* enter the same `synchronized` block at the same time.  And, that's not just in theory:  It often happens in well-designed programs.

Here's what two or more threads can *not* do:  Two or more threads can not synchronize on the *same object* at the same time.  If you want to insure that only one thread at a time can enter a particular method (but why?†) then you need to write the method so that all calls to it will synchronize on the same object.  That's easy to do if it's a static method because this:

```
class Foobar {
    synchronized MyType baz() { ... }
}
```

means the same as this:

```
class Foobar {
    MyType baz () {
        synchronized (Foobar.class) { ... }
    }
}
```

All calls to a *static* synchronized method synchronize on the class object that owns the method.

> [what prevents two threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time]?

The operating system.  Any JVM that you would want to use for real work uses *native threads* to implement Java threads.  A *native thread* is a thread that is created and managed by calls to the operating system.  In particular, it's a part of the operating system known as the *scheduler*.  I am not going to go into the details of how an operating system scheduler works---there's whole books written about that topic---but its job is to decide which threads get to run, when, and on what processor.

A typical scheduler uses queues to keep track of all of the threads that are not actually running.  One special queue, the *run queue*, holds threads that are ready to run, but waiting for a CPU to run on.  A thread on the run queue is called *runnable*.  A thread on any other queue is *blocked* (i.e., not allowed to run) until something happens that causes the scheduler to put it back on the run queue.

The operating system object corresponding to a Java *monitor* (See @TheLostMind's answer) often is called a *mutex* or a *lock*.  For each mutex, there is a queue of threads that are blocked, waiting to *enter* it.  A native thread enters a mutex by calling the operating system.  That gives the operating system the opportunity to pause the thread and add it to the mutex's queue if some other thread is already in the mutex.  When a thread leaves a mutex, that's a system call too; and it gives the scheduler the opportunity to pick one thread off the mutex's queue, and put it back on the run queue.

Like I said, the details of *how* the scheduler does those things go way too deep to talk about here.  Google is your friend.

---

† Don't worry about which threads can enter which method at the same time.  Worry instead about which threads touch which *data*.  The purpose of synchronization is to allow one thread to temporarily put your data into a state that you don't want other threads to see.

Answer (score 3):

In the Java language, each Object has what is called a Monitor, which basically is a lock.

This lock is what powers Object methods such as wait / signal / signalAll that are available on every objects.

When using the synchronized keyword, what happens behind the scenes is that the compiler writes code that acquires the monitor (the lock) and releases it when invocation is complete.

If the method is static, the Monitor that is accessed is that of the Class object.

You can read more about this keyword here :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Answer (score 2):

One thread (first) acquires a lock on the object, and another thread waits for getting lock of that object.

Once task is done, first thread sends notification to waiting threads using `notify()` and `notifyAll()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

**What is happening inside this method ?**

When you say a (instance level) method is synchronized, A thread must first get a lock on the Object (i.e, first hold the *monitor* of that object) to access it. As long as one thread holds the *lock* / *monitor*, other threads cannot access it. because they cannot get a lock on the object (it is like door to the object).

**How does other thread not able to execute the same task to run same method.**

Because as long as one thread still holds the monitor, other threads wait. i.e, they *cannot* access the monitor themselves.So, they are blocked and will wait in the waiting set / queue for that object.

**join is applied on that particular thread. But how does the second thread in the pipeline knows about the task has been done by first thread.**

*Join()* ensures that the thread that calls join() on another thread, waits until the second thread completes its execution.

Note : A *happens before* relationship is established between the 2 threads when join is called. So that Whatever *happens* before a call to join or a return from join are always visible to other thread.

**Edit :**

```
Assume ThreadA and ThreadB are two threads running concurrently.

ThreadA
{
 run(){
 //some statements;
  x=10; // assume x to be some shared variable
 ThreadB.join();
// here ThreadA sees the value of "x" as 20. The same applies to synchronized blocks.
// Suppose ThreadA is executing in a Synchronized block of Object A, then after ThreadA //exits the synchronized block, then other threads will "always" see the changes made by //ThreadA
// some other statements
}
}

ThreadB{
run(){
//some statements
 x=20;
}
```

check : [Happens Before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html)

Comment: you mean to say join() is called on another thread. But above "Evan  Knowles" said it applies lock not join. I think both statements are contradictory.

Comment: @vermaraj - check my edit.. A *happens-before* relationship is created  in both cases (join() as well as synchronization. for joins, it will be until the joined thread returns / completes execution. For synchronized blocks, it is until the block ends.

Comment: means join and synchronized blocks are working together in above example.

Comment: Joins are about waiting for thread completion (roughly speaking, termination - when they no longer execute any code and are destroyed at the OS level). locks are about concurrent access. When You protect a method with `synchronized` You typically do not wish to imply anything related to thread termination (join), only inter-thread coordination (locks). No `join` occurs as part of using `synchronized`.